# how to design entities in typeorm if there is a center user table and different role tables

Tags: database-design, entity, nestjs, typeorm

suppose I am designing a school website, and there are many roles,like students , teachers, admins...

my DB design looks like this

[image]

then, consider easy to read and easy to save how to design entities in typeorm is better?

[UPDATED]
finally, i design like this,i just merge all role into a ROLE table,and role_type means different role, eg. 5 means admin, 3 means teacher, 2 means student.

however, there are 2 columns redundancy, the school_id and the class_id.
these 2 columns are not necessary to admin, cause admin does not belong to any one school or class, but if i try to places these 2 columns in to othere tatble to record, that seems another kind of waste and complex more 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would be tempted to:

1. Make all of the tables entities
2. Have @OneToOne relationships between your role tables and 'user'

That way your queries on the role tables can retrieve the 'user' relation generating a reasonable JSON representation:

```
{ 
  user_id: 11,
  phone: '555-444-3333',
  school_id: '1234567',
  user: {
    id: 11',
    nickname: 'Jack',
    username: 'jblack',
    ...
  }
}
```

Example entities

```
@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @OneToMany(type => Role, role => role.user)
  roles: Role[];

  @OneToMany(type => Student, student => student.user)
  students: Student[];

  //TODO add the rest
}


@Entity()
export class Role {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @ManyToOne(type => User, user => user.role)
  roles: Role[];

  //TODO add the rest
}
```

Comment: thanks, i updated my design, but looks still not prefect